# как преобразовать void (*Class::)() в void (*)()

Tags: c++, opengl

Дело в том, что я хочу в OpenGL в функцию glutDisplayFunc передать метод класса.

```
glutDisplayFunc(Render::drawFunction);
```

Вот тот метод, который я хочу передать.

```
void drawFunction();
```

Вот ошибка, которая возникает:

Аргумент типа `void (Render::*)()` несовместим с параметром типа `void(*)()`

[image: Ошибка, которая возникает]

Comment: Дело в том, что ваша функция, которую вы передаете, на самом деле не `void(*)(void)`, потому что она получает скрытый параметр - сам объект, для которого вызывается (`this`). Так что просто так - у вас не получится...

Comment: вот меня радует C++. Ни functional, ни bind, ни перемычки в виде лямбды, ниче не работает. Самое главное что asm похоже позволяет так делать, а язык нет

Comment: метод класса в таком случаи должен быть статическим.

Comment: Не знаю для чего нужен класс `Render`. Если у тебя класс в одном экземпляре `Render globalr;` создай в классе `static void drawFunctionS(){globalr.drawFunction();}`  и вызывай `glutDisplayFunc(Render::drawFunctionS);`

Comment: такая же ситуация ,немного помогло добавить this-> но проблему не решило